# High gnome-shell cpu on fresh 18.04 install

Tags: cpu, 18.04, gnome-shell

I just installed 18.04 desktop, with updates, LUKS and LVM, and third party drivers. Asus mobo, Ryzen 1300x cpu, 16GB ram, NVidia GLX 1030 graphics. As soon as I login, gnome-shell uses up to 85% of the four cores. Mouse lags badly, keyboard bounces (up to 10 of each character). Completely unusable. Can't do any diagnosis with it lagging so badly.

This is with login using Ubuntu Wayland option. Default Ubuntu option just crashes and takes me back to login prompt every time.

Anyone else seeing this? Lots of similar reports on older releases, but no consistency on solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do the fresh install, but rather updated from 17.10, and I started getting those crazy 5 fps interface lags and high CPU usage by gnome-shell - it helped me to run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, which fetched new nvidia drivers - it seemed to have positive impact on the system.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I just installed kde instead.